# Converting Each ExcelWork Book to CSV

Tags: excel, ssis-2012

I have excel file with multiple work books,

ex:

```
Product.xlsx has sheets 
        1) Info
        2) Plan
        3) Attributes
```

I would like to select only one workbook and convert into CSV using File system task. 
Output:

```
Info.csv, plan.csv, Attributes,csv.
```

I have used File system task, but it is only converting first workbook into CSV,but i would like to select each workbook as a separate CSV.
How can i acheive it using SSIS ?

Comment: Did you tried with Script task ?

Comment: I couldnt manage to splti them across